# Issue with Variable Scope in python

Tags: python

I am currently learning python and got stuck at one of the program. Here is the snippet

```
test_board = ['#','X','O','X','O','X','O','X','O','X']
print(test_board)
def place_marker(board, marker, position):
    board[position] = marker

place_marker(test_board, '$', 8)
print(test_board)
```

The output of above program is

```
['#', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X']
['#', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X', '$', 'X']
```

I am confused that how did the value of variable test_board got updated ?
I didn't set the global variable nor I am returning the value. 
Can someone please help me understand ?

Comment: In python, list are mutable object

Comment: When you pass a parameter to a function, you get a reference to the object that was given by the caller. If that object is mutable you can change it as you did with `board[position] = ...`. Now that you know that, the links given at the top should make more sense.

Comment: Yes. Thank you so much. Now I can proceed.